# Python script runs perfect in PyCharm but in terminal don't

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I really don't understand... If you need screenshots of some settings please tell me because I really don't know why it works in PyCharm but not outside Pycharm...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest
from datetime import datetime

class MYMaster(unittest.TestCase):

    def Test_login(self): 

<<<<< MY CODE >>>>>

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

If I right click in PyCharm on line `class MYMaster(unittest.TestCase):` and select option **Run 'Unittest in MYMaster**' it will send this code

```
C:\Users\MyNameIs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Users\MyNameIs\PycharmProjects\untitled\MyProject\MyMain.py::MYMaster true
Testing started at 15:42 ...

Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

If I right click on `def Test_login(self):`and select option **Run 'Unittest TestLogin**' it will send this code (But it runs entire code and give results).

```
C:\Users\MyNameIs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Users\MyNameIs\PycharmProjects\untitled\MyProject\MyMain.py::MYMaster::Test_login true
Testing started at 15:50 ...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now I decided to open the MyMain.py in Python IDLE where I clicked Run module and this are the results:

```
= RESTART: C:\Users\MyNameIs\PycharmProjects\untitled\MyProject\MyMain.py =

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

> In Pycharm under Tool>Python Integrated Tools  Default test runner =
>   Unittests Docstring format = reStructuredText Checked checkbox Analyze
>   Python code in docstrings

Comment: Is your indentation after you `__main__` statement how it is in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `unittest`s in Pycharm, Pycharm provides a wrapper that executes other code before your code.

To execute `unittest`s from the terminal, you should use this command, provided that you have `python` set in your `PATH`:

`python -m unittest /path/to/script_with_tests.py`

You should also make sure that your functions' names start with `test`, ie `test_login`.

From `unittest` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html):

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. **The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.**

Comment: Yes , PATH is set for Python. However I run the code in cmd.exe and it results with `C:\Users\MyNameIs>python -m unittest C:/Users/MyNameIs/PycharmProjects/untitled/MyProject/MyMain.py
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
` Can i remove that testing stuff Project is finished I want it to run as exe

Comment: In order for `unittest` to find your test functions, their names must begin with `test`. Change the function name to `test_login`.

Comment: Ok now it will execute the script but in terminal this part of code works in Pycharm and makes export and in terminal doesn't... `         mybook = open('archive' + datetime.now().strftime("%m_%y") + '.csv', 'a')
                    mybook.write('%20s,%20s\n'%(people, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")))
                    mybook.close()

        self.driver.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()`

Comment: @PythonMan `if name == 'main'` should be `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: Yes it is just text editor here change it. Terminal runs all code but skip this and runs in Pycharm.. Always something...